# How to get complex layout using flex grid css3?

Tags: html, css, next.js

**im trying to achieve this layout using flex and it should be responsive without any media query**

**flex or grid can anyone write css for this layout?**
i tried this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.box:first-child {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.box:nth-child(3n) {
  min-height: 70%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.box{
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.box:first-child{
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
.box:nth-child(5){
  flex: 1 0 66.66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For this to work, you need `flex-direction: column`, otherwise the boxes won't wrap the way you want. 
I replaced the border with a `box-shadow` for it not take up any space.
For flex elements use the flex property for sizing in the flex-direction.
`flex: [can-grow] [can-shrink] base;`
The `nth-child` selector wasn't correct.

Answer (score -1):

Create full width header and footer
Position sidebar next to main content area
Correct sizing of sidebar and main content area
Navigation elements positioning

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).